# Finding the pdf of the difference of minimum and maximum of a finite set of random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, density-function

Let $X_i$ $ (1\leq i\leq n)$ be identically distributed uniformly on $(0,1)$. Let $U = \min_i(X_i)$, $V = \max_i(X_i)$. Find the pdf of $V-U$

---

This is what I did. I found the cdf and differentiated.

$$F_{V-U}(x)= \mathbb{P}(V-U \leq x)$$

We fix two of the random variables as the minimum and maximum and we of course have $2\binom{n}{2}$ choices and for each choice we fix the minimum, find the probability for the maximum and integrate.

$$\int_0^1 x-u \quad du = x - \frac{1}{2}$$

So

$$F_{V-U}(x) = 2(x-0.5)\binom{n}{2} \quad x\in(0,1)$$

and cdf equals $0$ elsewhere.

So $f_{V-U}(x) = 2\binom{n}{2} \quad x\in(0,1)$

but this doesn't make much sense since it doesn't integrate to $1$ over the $(0,1)$ interval. How can I fix it? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Even before differentiating you should have noticed that $V-U \in [0,1]$ implies $F_{V-U}(1)=1$ and $F_{V-U}(0)=0$, but your cdf does not satisfy that.

Comment: @angryavian I did notice that but I don't see what's wrong with my reasoning for coming up with the cdf.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument for constructing the order statistic's density function is *almost* correct.   You want the count of ways to select two of the samples to be required values, times the density functions for each of those values, *times the probability that the remaining $n-2$ samples lie between these values*.

Next, it will be easier to integrate the probability of the complement.

$$\begin{align}F_{V-U}(x) =&~ 1- \mathsf P(V-U>x)
\\=&~ 1-\int_x^1\int_0^{v-x} f_{U,V}(u,v)\operatorname d u\operatorname d v
\\=&~ 1- n(n-1)\int_x^1\int_{0}^{v-x} f_X(u)(F_X(v)-F_X(u))^{n-2}f_X(v) \operatorname d u\operatorname d v\\ =&~ 1-n(n-1)\int_x^1\int_0^{v-x} (v-u)^{n-2}\operatorname d u\operatorname d v \end{align}$$