# Probability of $n$ uniformly distributed points occuring within $m$ units of distance of each other

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose $U_i \sim \mathcal{U_{[0, 1]}}$ are independent uniformly distributed random variables over the interval $[0, 1]$. I believe the notation for the probability of **two** realisations of $U_i$ occurring within 0.5 units of each other is the following:
$$ \mathbb{P} \Bigl( \lvert U_1 - U_2 \rvert < \frac{1}{2} \Bigr) . $$
To generalise the statement above, am I correct to say that the probability of $n$ realisations of $U_i$ occurring within $0 \leq m \leq 1$ units of each other is
$$ \Bigl[ \mathbb{P} \Bigl( \lvert U_1 - U_2 \rvert < m \Bigr) \Bigr]^p $$
where $p = {n \choose 2}$?

Comment: No.  The variables in the sequence $(\lvert U_i-U_j\rvert)_{1\leq i<j\leq n}$ are not independent.  Try it with $n=3, m=.25$.

Comment: However, as $n$ grows *large*, the count for pairwise independent members of the sequence grows exponentially larger than the count for dependent members, so you may claim an *approximation*.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Do you have a hint/answer on how to write the generalised probability? So far I've only been able to come up with some overly complicated algorithmic or recurrence relation ideas.

Comment: By "$n$ realisations of $U_i$ occurring within $0 \leq m \leq 1$" you mean that all pairs are at distance less than $m$ ? That would be $P(\max_{i,j} | U_i - U_j| < m)$

Answer (score 2):

By "$n$ realisations of $U_i$ occurring within $0 \leq m \leq 1$" you mean that all pairs are at distance less than $m$ ? That would be $P(\max_{i,j} | U_i - U_j| < m)$ or , equivalently $$P( U_{(n)} - U_{(1)} < m)$$ where $U_{(n)}$,$U_{(1)}$ are resp the maximum and the minimum.

Of course, the above only amounts to denoting the *event*, not to computing its probability.

For that, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824986/finding-the-pdf-of-the-difference-of-minimum-and-maximum-of-a-finite-set-of-rand).

Comment: Not quite. Suppose we have k lots of $U_i$. I would like to know the probability that all the pairs in $n \leq k$ such $U_i$ are at a distance less than $m$ from each other. I suppose the answer would then be
    $$ [\mathbb{P}(U_{(n)} - U_{(1)} < m)]^q $$
where $q = {k \choose n}$, or possibly
    $$ q \mathbb{P}(U_{(n)} - U_{(1)} < m) ? $$